# sorting not all of columns in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, columnsorting

It is possible to sort a `DataGridView` by clicking on one of its `ColumnHeaderCell`. But I would like one column, containing the index of each row, to remain fixed.

What I mean is that when I click on another column header the grid rows should be sorted on the content of that column, all except the first column that contains the index of rows.

Sorry! I can't post image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want to **break** the rows: No you can't do that without re-creating them completely. A Row is a unit with its Columns and they can only move as one.

However if you want one column to always contain the visible row number you'll simply have to re-fill that column after each sort:

```
private void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.SuspendLayout();
   int yourindex = 0; // whichever column your index is at
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) 
                            row.Cells[yourindex].Value = row.Index;
   dataGridView1.ResumeLayout();

}
```

Note: By doing this you will lose the ability to re-create the original sort order. This may not be a problem. If it is you need to include an extra column called 'key' or 'old order' or whatever.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it takes so much time to recreate that column. for example I have 200 rows, for each clicking I must wait for some seconds to see the changes. maybe I must use another datagridview for that column but I thought if there is any better solution.

Comment: Huh? Filling 200 cells with a number shouldn't take more than a fraction of a second even on a slower machine. To avoid unnecessesary screen updates it may help to put the DGV into suspended layout mode, see edited annswer! But really I can add 20000 rows and it still takes under a second to set those indices! If you take more than even one second for 200 rows there is something else going on..!?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Int32 columnIndex = 1;// Index of the column you want as to be not sortable
DataGridView.Columns[columnIndex].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

and make sure you do this after populating data.